# R Session Aborted - R encountered a fatal error

Tags: r, linux, rstudio, fatal-error, seurat

I'm using Seurat package in RStudio and every time I try to use the function Read10X_h5 the R session aborts due to a fatal error. I've tried to just run the function in R console and it also crashes. I have R version 4.2.2 and RStudio version 2022.12.0+353, and I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS.

I'm analysing single-cell RNA sequencing data and the Read10X_h5 function is supposed to just be a simple function to read the h5 file and to then create a variable. I was able to use this function in another computer with the same version of R, so I can't think of what the problem might be with mine. It should also be noted that I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.5 in a Virtual Machine since I have a Mac that's quite old and couldn't use my software to download the latest RStudio version. I don't know if it being in a Virtual Machine will have anything to do with it, but just in case.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: On your VM, can you open a Terminal type `R` or maybe `R --vanilla` to open R, then `source(<path to your script>)` to rule out RStudio?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the memory is too small,I've had this problem before, just use a server with more memory.